# GetComponent Cannot Implicitly Convert type "Class" to GameController

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game system where the player uses the sling, and when he hits a target and destroys it, he gets score, but i can't Convert a different script into the gameobject. through getcomponent.

I've encountered this problem in the past and Changing FindGameObjectsWithTag helped it earlier, but now it doesn't and I still don't get it why this is happening, since after i restarted unity once and wrote the WHOLE project again it worked perfectly fine. but i don't want to do it this time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score { get; private set; }
    public Text ScoreText;
    private static GameController _instance;
    public static GameController Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                var obj = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController");
                if (obj != null)
                {
                      _instance = obj.GetComponent<SlingBackController>();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }  
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
        }
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Score = 0; 
    }

    public void AddToScore(int points)
    {
        if(points >0)
        {
            Score += points;
            ScoreText.text = Score.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The Error is at the this line :
_instance = obj.GetComponent();

its supposed to work perfectly fine with no issues but apparently it has and i don't understand them very well.

Comment: _"its supposed to work perfectly fine"_ why should it? Does `SlingBackController` derive from `GameController`? If not, this cannot work.

Comment: What is `SlingBackController`? Does it inherit from `GameController`?

Comment: Also let me correct your understanding here: `GetComponent` searches and returns the reference of a certain component attached to your GameObject. It doesn't "convert" the GameObject to another type.

Comment: Please paste the exception you have verbatim. Replacing some phrase in an exception (such as your replacement of something with `"Class"`) adds another obstacle in diagnosing the cause of the problem, and it also can make the question harder to find for people who have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @Ruzihm I'ld say from the code the type missmatch is pretty obvious though

Comment: @derHugo yes, this time it is obvious, and that's part of what allowed me to call it out this time. Correcting poor convention when it's obvious leads to less occurrences that aren't obvious.

Comment: @Itay actually the whole `FindWithTag` part is completely redundant .. you could use `FindObjectOfType` .. anyway I would rather change my scripts not having to use `Instance` in `Awake` .. then you would never need this at all since it would be set anyway after `Awake` is done..

Comment: Heres the SlingBackController code, my bad. forgot to add it.
https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IT461
(I cant get paste the whole script. because its too big).

Comment: @derHugo Interesting, What can i replace it with so it would do the same action as its supposed to be? 

I upgraded my visual studio and unity not so long ago and didn't practice with the new ways and methods that people use now :(

could u tell me a way to replace the lines with something more simplified? :)

Comment: As everyone already told you the issue is simply that `GameController != SlingBackController` you can't simply mix the types. It seems like you simply have a typo there from copying the code from one class to the other without changing the type accordingly. And afaik [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) is not that new ;)

Comment: @derHugo I learnt it from a course ;P

Comment: Well, you're trying to assign an instance of a `GameController` to the `_instance` field. So consider what you would need to change about `obj.GetComponent<SlingBackController>();` to have it look for a `GameController` component instead of a `SlingBackController` component.

Answer (score 0):

Change `private static GameController _instance;` to `private static SlingBackController _instance;`

The problem is that the computer expects a GameController but then you assign it a SlingBackController here `_instance = obj.GetComponent<SlingBackController>();`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Nope I guess he should rather change the line to `GetComponent<GameController>()` .. would make much more sense

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `SlingBackController` reference to a field with the type `GameController`.

As said it seems like you simply copied the code from `SlingBackController` into your `GameController` but forgot to exclude the type for `GetComponent` accordingly.

It should rather be

```
public static GameController Instance
{
    get
    {
        if(!_instance)
        {
            var obj = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController");
            if (obj)
            {
                  _instance = obj.GetComponent<GameController>();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }  
    private set
    {
        _instance = value;
    }
}
```

Or the more efficient using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

```
public static GameController Instance
{
    get
    {
        if(!_instance) _instance = FindObjectOfType<GameController>();

        return _instance;
    }  
    private set
    {
        _instance = value;
    }
}
```

However this is the so called "lazy initialization" meaning it is only done if needed.

Since you are setting the value in `Awake` anyway you actually rather should simply make sure that no class relies on `Instance` before the `Start` method.

My golden rule usually is:

- use **`Awake`** for initialization of the class own's values and for `GetComponent` calls.
- use **`Start`** whenever the class relies on another classes values initialized first.

Sometimes this isn't possible then you can use either the [Script execution order settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) in order to configure in which order your scripts are executed or as a fallback use your code for a lazy initialization.